# when decompressing a file, remove unwanted lines before writing them into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

I get an error when trying to decompress a file, remove the lines that I am not interested in, and finally write the remaining lines into a file. Here is my code:

```
import gzip, os, sys
dataset_names=[]
dir_path=('local drive path')
dataset_names= os.listdir(dir_path)
count=0
read_zip = [];
for dataset in dataset_names:
        each_dataset=os.path.join(dir_path+'\\'+dataset+'\\'+'soft'+'\\'+dataset+'_full'+'.soft')
        with gzip.open(each_dataset+'.gz', 'rb') as each_gzip_file:
            if count == 2: # I wanted to check with 2 datasets first
                continue;
            for line in each_gzip_file:    
                if line.startwith !=('#', '!', '^'):
                    continue;
                read_zip.append('\t' + line);
            with open('name of a file', 'wb') as f:                   

                    f.writelines(read_zip)
        print(dataset);
        count+=1;
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
 AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'startwith'
```

then I tried to change it to this code:

```
......
.......            
for line in each_gzip_file:
                if not PY3K:
                    if lines.startwith != ('#', '!', '^'):
                        continue;
                    lines.append(line)

                else:
                    lines.append(line.decode('cp437'))                
                    makeitastring = ''.join(map(str, lines))
               with open('fine name', 'wb') as f:   

                    my_str_as_bytes = str.encode(str(,lines))
                    f.writelines(makeitastring)
```

This time got this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I also changed it with the following, but it did not work either. It was like it was iterating over and over again:

```
for line in each_gzip_file:
                read_zip.append(line);
                for x in read_zip:
                    if str(x).startswith != ('#', '!', '^'):
                     continue;                         
                else:
                    final.append(x);                        

                with open('file name', 'ab') as f:  

                f.writelines(final)
```

Am I missing anything? 
Thanks,

Comment: Can you specify which line actually triggers the error?

Comment: @Saustin 
for line in each_gzip_file:    
                if line.startwith !=('#', '!', '^'):
                    continue;

Comment: did you try `str(line).startwith !=... `?

Comment: @ VBB I did. Here is that error for that one:  
   if str(line).startwith !=('#', '!', '^'):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startwith'

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors I see. First, you're misspelling the method name. It is `bytes.startswith()`, not `bytes.startwith()`. Note the "s" between "start" and "with".

Second, the code `line.startswith != ('#', '!', '^')` is not doing what you think. `startswith()` is a method of `bytes` objects, and what you want is to call that method with `'#'`, etc. as the arguments. Right now, you're asking "is this method *equal* to this tuple of three strings?". That's meaningless in this cases, but Python will happily return `False`.

What you want is `line.startswith((b'#', b'!', b'^'))`. (The `b` is necessary to distinguish strings from bytes, as they're different in Python 3.) This will return `True` if the line begins with any of those three characters.

Comment: Thanks @bnaecher but I still get an error:if line.startswith(b'#', b'!', b'^'):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: `bytes.startswith` takes a bytes object or tuple of bytes objects as first argument, but you passed them in as 1st, 2nd and 3rd argument because you left away the brackets. The 2nd and 3rd argument are expected to be integers, which results in the error message you see. Read bnaecker's code again, it's correct there.

Comment: @bnaecker Thank you! you were right and I was off by a pair of parenthesis!